# Should I be importing specific functions to make PyInstaller file smaller?

Tags: pyinstaller

When using PyInstaller `--onefile`, it can be slow to open the `.exe` file created and the file can be quite large. I think this is due to all the files included, such as all the imports in the python script. Is it advisable to only import the specific functions or classes from a module that I'm actually using, or does this not actually decrease what is packaged with PyInstaller? For example, would it be better to do

```
from numpy import array
```

instead of simply

```
import numpy
```

Or will PyInstaller still package all of numpy in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just spent some time deep diving into this same thing. And from what I found:

*pyinstaller packages the whole module either way*.

Best ways to keep the exe slim is:

1. creating a virtual environment and only installing the needed modules for your code.
2. using upx (https://coderslegacy.com/python/pyinstaller-upx/)

(Edit to add Example)

Example:

Code 1

```
import numpy as np
a = np.sin(5)
```

Code 2

```
from numpy import sin
a = sin(5)
```

And

```
pyinstaller --onefile file.py
```

exe size in both cases: **20772 KB**